# Google Play Custom App Publishing API to publish a private app in C#

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Google Play Custom App Publishing API
to publish a private app using C# and I'm not able to find a way to upload or pass the APK.

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/custom-app-api/publish) gives an example of how to do it :

```
Path apkPath = Paths.get("PATH_TO_APK");
ByteArrayContent apk =
    new ByteArrayContent("application/octet-stream", Files.readAllBytes(apkPath));

CustomApp appMetadata =
    new CustomApp()
      .setTitle("APPLICATION TITLE").setLanguageCode("en_US");

CustomApps.Create request =
    apiClient.accounts() // Playcustomapp apiClient
      .customApps().create(DEV_ACCOUNT_ID, appMetadata, apk);

CustomApp response = request.execute();
```

I've imported the NuGet package `Google.Apis.Playcustomapp.v1` and created appMetaData

```
CustomApp appMetadata = new CustomApp() {
    Title = "Whatsapp",
    LanguageCode = "en-US"
};
```

There are 2 API requests available and they are :

```
var createRequest = new AccountsResource.CustomAppsResource.CreateRequest(
    service, appMetadata, 9197907806840XXXXX);
```

```
var createMediaUpload = new AccountsResource.CustomAppsResource.CreateMediaUpload(
    service, appMetadata, 9197907806840XXXXX, ms, "application /octet-stream");
```

Both of which give me error 404. This is because I have not passed the APK which needs to be uploaded. 
Where can I send this APK from? There's a `stream` parameter in the `CreateMediaUpload` but it doesn't help as well.

Errors :

`CreateRequest` : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path ''. How do I pass the path of the `APK` here?

`CreateMediaUpload` : The requested URL `/upload/9197907806840917992/customApps?uploadType=resumable` was not found on this server.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What is `ms` here? Is it a MemoryStream by any chance? I wonder whether you haven't rewound that after writing to it? It's also not clear what `9197907806840XXXXX` is, given that that's not a valid method argument - and currently you've got a rogue space in your content-type, which is also probably not helping.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes ```ms``` is a Stream which has the ```byteArray``` of the ```APK```.
```9197907806840XXXXX``` is my google developer account which is a required parameter.
And the space got added while copy, pasting. It's not present in my code.

Code for stream :


```ByteArrayContent apk =
                new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\lucky\Desktop\app-release.apk"));

      System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

      apk.CopyToAsync(ms);```

Comment: Right, so as I thought - that's a MemoryStream that if you read from it won't have any content. You've *written* to it, but the cursor is at the end of the stream. If you use `ms.Position = 0;` that will rewind it, so there's content to upload.

Comment: (I don't know anything about this specific API, I'm afraid. I'm just trying to spot potential issues.)

Comment: @JonSkeet ah yes, I did set the ```ms.Position=0``` now but still doesn't help. Getting the same error. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you have found is a Java Sample. After some random guessing on how to put the pieces together, i finally got it.

Keep in mind, there is some magic undocumented restriction about how often you can create private apps per day. Something about 15 apps per day. After that you hit that limit you will get this message error:

apkNotificationMessageKeyReachedUploadLimit

```
static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var email = "yourserviceaccountmail";
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(email)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { PlaycustomappService.Scope.Androidpublisher }
            }.FromPrivateKey("client_secrets.json"));

        CustomApp appMetadata = new CustomApp();
        appMetadata.Title = "YOUR APP";
        appMetadata.LanguageCode = "en_US";

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PlaycustomappService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Custom Apps API Sample",
        });

        var acc = new AccountsResource(service);
        using (var stream = new FileStream("app-release.apk", FileMode.Open))
        {
            long devIAccountd = 12345678L;
            var app = acc.CustomApps.Create(appMetadata, devIAccountd, stream, "application/octet-stream");
            var response = await app.UploadAsync();
            if (response.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Someting went wrong:");
                Console.WriteLine(response.Exception.Message);
            }
            if (response.Status == Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Succeeded!");
            }
        }
    }
```